# Functional Analysis Exercise 16 Walter Rudin Chapter 1

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

This is in reference to Question 16 which is referring to 1.44 and 1.46 section of Walter Rudin's Functional Analysis.
Please help me in starting this problem.

[image]

Below is the reference of the book pdf

https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis-_-rudin-2th.pdf

Comment: People who don't have a copy of Rudin handy have no idea what Sect 1.44 or Section 1.46 say.... You should include ALL relevant information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{H_n\}$is  another sequence of compact sets satisfying the same properties then $H_n \subset \cup K_m^{0}$ because the interiors of the sets $K_m$ cover $\Omega$. By compactness, $H_n$ is contained in some $K_m$. Hence uniform convergence of a sequence of functions on each $K_m$ implies  uniform convergence of the sequence on each $H_n$ and conversely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I started with the same way but what to do in the second part, the last line of the question "Do the same for infinity omega"

Comment: @Pawan Instead  of uniform convergence of just the functions you consider uniform convergence of the functions and their derivatives up to a certain order. This is will give the  result for $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: I didn't understand "uniform convergence of the functions and their derivatives up to a certain order".
If it's ok can you please share the complete solution with me, I will be very much thankful to you.

Comment: @Pawan That is how the topology of $C^{\infty}$ is defined in section 1.46. The semi-norms generating the topology are suprema of derivatives up to order $1,2,3,...$

Comment: Please share the complete solution if possible, it will be really helpful for me.